# How to get all pages details by filtering by cms page type?

Tags: django, django-cms

I am new to django and I want to get all page details filtering by page type in django-cms.

I used below def to display it in a template.

```py
    def cms_detailed_view(request):
      all_pages = Title.objects.public().values()
      context= {'pages': all_pages}
      return render(request, 'node-detailed.html', context)
```

It gives all pages. But I wants to filter it by page type. I don't know how to use filter method to filter by page type like

```py
    all_pages = Title.objects.filter(type="pagetype")
```

Comment: `type` isn't a field on the `Title` model, where did you get that from? And if you want CMS pages, you need the page model; https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/develop/cms/models/pagemodel.py#L149

Comment: I know the `Title` model doesn't contain `type`. I also tried the `Page` model. But I can't filter by page type. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: That's because pages don't have a type. There is a `PageType` proxy of pages though; https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/develop/cms/models/pagemodel.py#L1634